# Large datasets: mysql_unbuffered_query with innodb?

Tags: php, mysql, innodb, myisam

Basically I need to operate on largedata set, so I started thinking that i could use mysql_unbuffered_query to don't load all results in RAM.

But I read that while I am fetching row I can't run any other query on the same table. I wonder is this still true if the table is innodb?

does Innodb use row-level locking while performing a mysql_unbuffered_query ?

The pseudocode is:

```
$q = mysql_unbuffered_query("SELECT * FROM largeTable");
while($r = fetch($q)) {
 if (some condition)
   mysql_query("UPDATE largeTable SET field = somevalue WHERE id = someid");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason that you can't run another query is that the results of the query are not prefetched and you are dealing with a cursor. Still, you can open another connection to deal with other queries.

Keep in mind, that there are several settings in MySQL, affecting how long the connection will be kept open after the query was executed, if the dataset is large, the server can close connection before you've processed the query (see wait_timeout and net_write_timeout)

Good alternative is to perform the query in a loop, limiting the number of rows, and using `WHERE pk > value ORDER BY pk ASC`, where `pk` is the primary key, and `value` the last value retrieved from the previous query (as if you implement just limit,offset the performance will degrade on large offsets)